# Liverpool has decreased

Tags: grammar, word-order

*By defeating Everton, Liverpool **has decreased the difference to two points behind leading Manchester City**.* – ***Manchester City has now two points more than Liverpool.***

I would like to ask whether the passage in bold sounds naturally in English. I am not sure how to express that in the PL Manchester City is now leading with 38 points and the second Liverpool has 36 points.

Comment: By defeating Everton, Liverpool has/have narrowed the gap with Manchester City who have 38 points, two more.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So the sentence "Manchester City has/have two points more than Liverpool" is OK.

Comment: @bart-leby  It's fine.  There are of course many other ways to state this as a simple fact, but with the use of the action verb "decrease" the report implies it's a situation *in flux*, that it could *rapidly change*, to instill a perhaps premature sense of excitement.  Another example:  *"The latest polls show that the underdog candidate has **narrowed the gap** between her and the incumbent by 3 points"*  Sounds exciting, but kind of meaningless if the underdog is still 10 points behind.

Comment: @Andrew – OK. By thinking over the question I have found that I have problems with saying that someone has something lesser amount. For example, Jane has three books and John six books. I would say "Jane has three books lesser than Jane". Bot not at all sure.

Comment: @bart-leby *Jane has three **fewer** books than John*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Manchester City has now two points more than Liverpool.

Is fine.

> Liverpool has decreased the difference to two points behind leading Manchester City.

Is Okay.  I'd use "reduced" instead of "decreased".  In addition, I'd use an appositive: "the leaders, Manchester City". And I'd think about whether I wanted to treat the teams as singular "Liverpool has..." or as plural groups "Liverpool have"  (this latter form is more common in Brit Eng than in US Eng)

As noted in comments:

> Liverpool have narrowed the gap to two points behind the leaders, Man City

Is one more alternative. There are many others: "... closed to ..."; "Liverpool now need only one win to overtake Man City..."